# How to align a span element inside a div?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

**UPDATE about duplicated question:** it is not the same question since I can not set the height of the containter div.

How to horizontally and vertically align a span element inside a div.

The div is resposive element, so it can takes several sizes.
The span has not set height nor the width

```
<div class="the-div">
   <span class="the-span" >span here</span>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
.the-span{top: 50%; text-align: center}
```

I don't want to use js for this.

Capture:[image]

Comment: align center you mean?

Comment: Have you tried adding `text-align:center` to the div class `the-div` ?

Comment: yes, I need to center the span inside the div, horizontally and vertically

Comment: @Lee yes, that works for horizontally. But I can't get the vertically alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform its position thusly:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div,
span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); /* <--offset top/left by half its own height/width */
  left: 50%; /* position half way within containing div */
  top: 50%; /* position half way within containing div */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: cleaner markup than what I had :)

Comment: @jbutler483 but in production OP has to use the markup which you posted because this is only good for demos and not real world

Comment: I can't get it working, I run your code and not working... look my capture I uploaded to the question.

Comment: I can not set the width and heigh for the div container. It is a responsive element.

Comment: @JPashs: In order for the `transform` property to work, you will require prefixing :)